# How to concatenate a string, variable and an array modifier into a variable in php

Tags: php

This my code and it doesnt concatenate at all.

```
${'dailystartend2'.$i} = explode("|",${"dailystartend".$i."[1]"});
```

What is the properway to do this? I cannot use array because exploding a string automtically convert into array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for dynamic variables add string part in between {} and use like normal variables

```
${'dailystartend2'.$i} = explode("|",${"dailystartend".$i}[1]);
```